# Why is subclass type not assignable to generic extends type?

Tags: typescript

Following code is giving an error (below). But if I change the Parent.method() return type to A, it compiles. What is the logic behind this? Why is B not assignable to T, since it extends from A ?

> TS2416: Property 'method' in type 'Child' is not assignable to the
> same property in base type 'Parent'.   Type '() => B' is not
> assignable to type '() => T'.     Type 'B' is not
> assignable to type 'T'.       'B' is assignable to the constraint of
> type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of
> constraint 'A'.

```
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class Parent {
     public method<T extends A>(): T { // <---- return type
        ...
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public method(): B {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask

> Why is B not assignable to T, since it extends from A ?

But the compiler says that a problem is slightly different:

> 'B' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'.

For example, you could have:

```ts
class C extends A {}

const p1 = new Parent();
const r1 = p1.method<C>();
```

Expected type of r1 is C, if you would allow an overload with a fixed return type of B, this could result in a runtime error.

In this particular example I forced the generic argument to be C manually, but situation is pretty similar if it is inferred from one of arguments.

```ts
class A {}

class B extends A {}

class C extends A {}

class Parent {
     public method<T extends A>(p: T): T {
      return p;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public method(p: B): B { // Compiler error
      return p
    }
}

const p1 = new Parent();
const r1 = p1.method(new C());


const c2 = new Child();
const r2 = c2.method(new C());

console.log(r2);  // prints C, but inferred type is B
```

Comment: Ah you mean, compiler is warning me about, calling a sub class method using a parent class reference with wrong generic type? I was actually trying to understand what that error was saying.

Comment: @SankaDarshana As shown in the second example, the effect is also visible when calling through sub-class reference. The error says: `'B' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T'` which means B indeed extends A, `but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'.` which means: it is possible that there exists another subtype of A (in my example C) and method is called with this type, and not with B.